# Customization of only one field in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have my resource in ActiveAdmin with 12 fields. I want to edit the behavior of only one field. Do i have to rewrite the entire form or are there any ways for edit the field i'm interested in?

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "behaviour"?

Comment: I mean for example that i want to change a text field into a select field.

Comment: sure you can only change specific field. See my answer

Comment: did you try my answer? need any further help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way to customize only one field of the form. You'll have to code the entire form using Formtastic

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can keep the 11 fields with `f.inputs`
For example, to show an ActionText rich text input for field `description`:

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs

    rich_text_area :description
    actions
  end
```

P.s. I'm using Rails 5.2.3 & ActiveAdmin 2.1.0